# Monitor a table from Oracle db and run Workflow in Informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica

I'm new to Informatica, need help with my requirements.

1) I have a table **CS_pipe** which has columns named **'ReportName'** and **'Status'** in Oracle

2) When a report fails the Status column will have value **'Failed'**

3) I need to create a package that will pull value from this table and mail a group when the table status is 'Failed' informing them of the report failure.

Is it possible via Informatica? If yes how can it be done?

Comment: You will do the job easier, if the table would contain a primary key (to uniquely identify a record) and/or a creation timestamp.

Comment: This particular requirement could be handled better in Oracle itself. Informatica is used for ETL purpose. Although it doesn't mean that you cannot use it for sending email, but in your case, you should it in Oracle or OS level. Read this [article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow and schedule it to run at fixed intervals, like every 15 minutes, and read all the values `where Status = 'Failed'`, sending email message with the required content.

Then you'd need a way to prevent emails from getting sent for the same failed report over and over again. Depending on your requirements and available columns, you could create a datetiem variable to fetch only the latest status records. But that's a separate story.

Comment: Can you help me out with how this can be done? In Detail plz?

Comment: I need your engagement: do a POC, give it a try, get back with any problems. I'll do my best to help you out.